# Rigging and weight painting problem

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

How to make sure that the hands do not fall through the body and how to correct the stretching and strange shape of the model during animation

[image]

Blender project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/120YW4I9fyklgBfr9wC4--R0NJgrCSIWc?usp=sharing